# How can I prevent text-area to go to a new line?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to style my description column

```
<template v-slot:item.description="{ item }" class="description" style="overflow-wrap: normal">
{{ item.description }}
</template>
```

CSS

```
<style scoped>
>>> .description {
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    color: red; //TEST
}
</style>
```

[image]

Doesn't seem to take effect ! Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `white-space: nowrap;` rule :

```
<style scoped>
>>> .description {
  white-space: nowrap;
    color: red; //TEST
}
</style>
```

Comment: That style doesn't seem to take effet :(

Comment: try to remove `>>>`

Comment: I did, and I also added !important. No luck 

Comment: I just asked a new question, since they are slightly diff. If you know ... please help me there.